# I receive "Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child." with TouchableWithoutFeedback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, frontend

I receive the following error:

```
Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
```

When I use the 'TouchableWithoutFeedback' component with ReactNative:

```
 return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
      Keyboard.dismiss();}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header />
        <Exercises exercises={exercises} handleChange={handleChange} handlePress={handlePress} exercise={exercise}/>
      </View>
`    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
```

I am not sure why because everything is wrapper in a View component. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the content of `View` with a react fragment:

```
 return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
      Keyboard.dismiss();}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <>
        <Header />
        <Exercises exercises={exercises} handleChange={handleChange} handlePress={handlePress} exercise={exercise}/>
       </>
      </View>
`    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
```